# Replacement for broken USB transceiver

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, mouse

I broke the USB transceiver that came with my Microsoft wireless media desktop 1000 mouse/keyboard bundle. Anyone know where I can get a (inexpensive) replacement transceiver, besides Microsoft? They won't replace it, suggested getting a universal transceiver. Where would I get one and how would I know the right one to get?

Comment: Unless it's a bluetooth system, it's unlikely there are universal transceivers for this.

The troubleshooting document says to call the Microsoft Order Desk at (800) 360-7561 to order replacement parts. Is this the number you called to try and get a replacement?

Comment: not bluetooth - apparently its 27mhz RF with some sort of encryption

Comment: I have same mouse, called this number, a guy told me that it's an old hardware, they don't have replacements for this. The only was somehow to get is is to find a **universal** transceiver. But were can I possibly find it :)

Comment: [How to replace a USB wireless mouse receiver in this case?](http://superuser.com/questions/624172/how-to-replace-a-usb-wireless-mouse-receiver-in-this-case)

Comment: [Is there something like a “Universal 2.4GHz Receiver” for wireless peripherals?](https://superuser.com/questions/457814/is-there-something-like-a-universal-2-4ghz-receiver-for-wireless-peripherals)