# Is there something like a "Universal 2.4GHz Receiver" for wireless peripherals?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I have recently been given the keyboard and mouse set, [Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Desktop 7000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-gb/p/natural-ergonomic-desktop-7000).  This however came **without** the receiver.  Is there anywhere I could get a replacement receiver for this?

I heard somewhere that I need a "Universal 2.4GHz Transceiver/Receiver" and it would work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question at hand, I don't think there is something like a universal receiver for wireless peripherals.

**But**, you might be able to get a replacement for that part from Microsoft directly. They have an interesting knowledgebase article, [How to replace Microsoft software or hardware, order service packs, and replace product manuals](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326246), which outlines the process.

You told me on chat that you're from the UK and I couldn't see any contact information for the UK in that article. So, I took the liberty to contact Microsoft and inquire about this information:

> For hardware replacement, you can contact Microsoft Direct Services at **0800 032 4479**<sup>1</sup>. They are available on weekdays from 8:00 A.M. to 6:00 P.M. (excluding Bank holidays)
>
> <sup>1</sup>: Calls provided by BT to the 0844 number above will be charged at 5 pence per minute. A Call Set-Up Fee of up to 6 pence per call applies to calls from Residential lines. Mobile and other providers? costs may vary. See http://www.bt.com/pricing for details.

Comment: I instead bought a new keyboard because that worked out better for me.  This answer would solve the problem though.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you'll be able to get a new receiver is by writing off to MS or whoever market the keyboards. AFAIK, the MS keyboards (And most other wireless keyboards) use their own communication schemes. You could, in theory, build your own reciever with an XBee and an Arduino, but it wouldn't be worth the work.

TL;DR: No. You can't.

Comment: The receiver used by Microsoft is more or less standard across their wireless keyboard product lines.  All one would need to do is get a receiver from perhaps a wireless keyboard that didn't work.  Any supported receiver itself can be paired to any wireless MS keyboard.

Comment: That will not work. It has some security to prevent this..

Answer (score -1):

In answer to your question: Yes, there is a universal transceiver for most wireless keyboards and mouse. You will need to know your brand and model of course. Go to your local computer store or a computer repair shop. You can also order the transceiver on line.

Comment: This answer isn't complete.  The reciever is NOT standard since were not talking about a Bluetooth keyboard.