# How to replace a USB wireless mouse receiver in this case?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, mouse

My mouse is quite good, but unfortunately the USB wireless receiver is as big as an adult's little finger (pinky). It breaks easily when the laptop is moved. I want a micro receiver and the company does not make those for my model of the mouse.

Okay, I already saw this question and it does not answer my question - [Replacement for broken USB transceiver](https://superuser.com/questions/347868/replacement-for-broken-usb-transceiver)

I searched online and also called the company. I don't think there is a USB replacement for my brand of mouse. So, I have to buy the whole mouse just for the receiver.

Is there any way I could find out how this works and then use the receiver of another mouse by same company or different and then use it with my mouse ?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's RF and not Bluetooth, it's likely using some manufacturer specific communication.  It's likely you'll be able to use a receiver from the same company, but unlikely you could use a different company's.

Comment: Yes, find the specs and frequency of the mouse and sync it to a new receiver that uses the same

Comment: @ernie - please see the comment below yours.

Comment: @Raystafarian - Even if it uses the frequency a reciver for Mouse A is unlikely going to work for Mouse B

Comment: @Ramhound Right, that's why I mentioned specs. I wasn't disagreeing with you. Sometimes an IR receiver card could work as well.

Comment: Mice are cheap.  Just buy a new mouse with a compact receiver.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there something like a "Universal 2.4GHz Receiver" for wireless peripherals?](http://superuser.com/questions/457814/is-there-something-like-a-universal-2-4ghz-receiver-for-wireless-peripherals)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no universal RF wireless mouse/keyboard receivers, and a given company's RF wireless/mouse keyboard receiver will not work with another's.

You should get a small [USB extender cable](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/StarTech.com-USB-2.0-Extension-Cable-A-to-A-USB-extension-cable-10-ft/2274398.aspx?cm_mmc=ShoppingFeeds-_-GoogleBase-_-Cables/USB/FireWire%20Connectivity-_-2274398_StarTech.com%20USB%202.0%20Extension%20Cable%20A%20to%20A%20-%20USB%20extension%20cable%20-%2010%20ft_STP-USBEXTAA10BK), and  a length of [velcro tape](http://www.grainger.com/Grainger/VELCRO-Fastener-15A771?gclid=CI3KsdKTy7gCFQai4AodgUoAWw&cm_mmc=PPC:GooglePLA-_-Hardware-_-Hardware%20Supplies-_-15A771&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=15A771&ef_id=UdyDDQAABf1kewfd:20130725171925:s).  Cut the velcro tape to fit on the back of the dongle, and find a good spot on the back of laptop lid to put the other half of the tape.  This will prevent you from smashing it by accidentally scraping it against a surface.

It won't look too pretty but it'll prevent your dongle from getting broken.